# setOnAction within another setOnAction not working for arrays of buttons in Javafx

Tags: java

I'm actually not sure about the title because I don't know if that is the real problem.
I'm making this application that the user clicks on a plus or minus button to get a number of people, then for each person there are two more plus and minus buttons to get another number that has to be multiplied by 15 and the result is shown in a TextField.
i don't know why my code is giving me this error: 
"Local variable i defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final".
I commented the code where the error is shown.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Thanks very much.

```
int arrayLength;
int counter = 1;
double bc = 15.00;

Button[] baggagePlus;
Button[] baggageMinus;
Label[] baggageCounter;
Label[] costBaggage;
CheckBox[] checkReturn;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    stage = primaryStage;
    stage.setTitle("");
    stage.setResizable(false);

    pane = new BorderPane();
    pane.setStyle("-fx-background: #CEF6D8;");

    centerPane1 = new Pane();

    GridPane mainGrid = new GridPane();
    mainGrid.setPadding(new Insets(150, 0, 0, 100));
    mainGrid.setVgap(50);

    noPassGrid = new GridPane();
    noPassGrid.setHgap(10);

    adultPlus = new Button("+");
    adultPlus.setMinWidth(50);
    adultPlus.setFont(Font.font("Verdana", 20));
    GridPane.setConstraints(adultPlus, 1, 0);

    adultPlus.setOnAction(e -> {
        plus(adultCounter);
        getArraySize();
    });

    adultCounter = new Label("1");
    adultCounter.setFont(Font.font("Verdana", 20));
    GridPane.setConstraints(adultCounter, 2, 0);

    adultMinus = new Button("-");
    adultMinus.setMinWidth(50);
    adultMinus.setFont(Font.font("Verdana", 20));
    GridPane.setConstraints(adultMinus, 3, 0);

    adultMinus.setOnAction(e -> {
        minus(adultCounter);
            getArraySize();
    });

noPassGrid.getChildren().addAll(adultPlus, adultCounter, adultMinus);

    GridPane.setConstraints(noPassGrid, 0, 2);

    mainGrid.getChildren().addAll(noPassGrid);


    search = new Button("SEARCH");
    search.setPrefSize(300, 100);
    search.setFont(new Font("Verdana", 30));
    passengersGrid = new GridPane();
    search.setOnAction(e -> {

        passengersGrid.setPadding(new Insets(150, 0, 0, 450));
        passengersGrid.setVgap(20);
        passengersGrid.setHgap(20);

        for(int i=0; i<arrayLength; i++) {

            baggagePlus[i] = new Button("+");
            baggagePlus[i].setMinWidth(50);
            baggagePlus[i].setFont(Font.font("Verdana", 20));
            GridPane.setConstraints(baggagePlus[i], 5, i);



            baggageCounter[i] = new Label("0");
            baggageCounter[i].setFont(Font.font("Verdana", 20));
            GridPane.setConstraints(baggageCounter[i], 6, i);

            baggagePlus[i].setOnAction(
                    new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            plus(baggageCounter[i]); //The "i" is underlined showing error 
            doublePrice(checkReturn[i], costBaggage[i], bc, baggageCounter[i]);
                        }
        });

            baggageMinus[i] = new Button("-");
            baggageMinus[i].setMinWidth(50);
            baggageMinus[i].setFont(Font.font("Verdana", 20));
            GridPane.setConstraints(baggageMinus[i], 7, i);

            baggageMinus[i].setOnAction(
                new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                    public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
        minus(baggageCounter[i]); //The "i" is underlined showing error
        doublePrice(checkReturn[i], costBaggage[i], bc, baggageCounter[i]);
                    }
        });


            checkReturn[i] = new CheckBox();
            checkReturn[i].setFont(Font.font(20));
            GridPane.setConstraints(checkReturn[i], 10, i);

            checkReturn[i].setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
    //The "i" is underlined showing error
    doublePrice(checkReturn[i], costBaggage[i], bc, baggageCounter[i]);
                }
        });

            costBaggage[i] = new Label("€0.00");
            costBaggage[i].setFont(Font.font("Verdana", 25));
            GridPane.setConstraints(costBaggage[i], 18, i);

            passengersGrid.getChildren().addAll(baggagePlus[i], baggageCounter[i], baggageMinus[i], checkReturn[i], costBaggage[i]);

}
    });



    centerPane1.getChildren().addAll(mainGrid, passengersGrid);
    pane.setCenter(centerPane1);

    bottom1 = new AnchorPane(search);
    bottom1.setPadding(new Insets(0, 0, 100, 0));
    AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(search, 150.0);
    pane.setBottom(bottom1);



    scene = new Scene(pane, 1200, 600);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

}


public void getArraySize() {
    arrayLength = counter;

    baggagePlus = new Button[arrayLength];
    baggageMinus = new Button[arrayLength];
    baggageCounter = new Label[arrayLength];
    costBaggage = new Label[arrayLength];
    checkReturn = new CheckBox[arrayLength];
}

public void plus(Label l) {
    if(counter < 8) {
        counter++;
        l.setText("" + counter);
    }
}

public void minus(Label l) {
    if(counter > 1) {
        counter--;
        l.setText("" + counter);
    }
}

public void doublePrice(CheckBox cb, Label ll, double bc, Label l) {
    if(cb.isSelected()) {
        ll.setText("€" + df.format(2 * bc * (Double.parseDouble(l.getText()))));
        }
        else {
            ll.setText("€" + df.format(bc * (Double.parseDouble(l.getText()))));
        }
}



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is exactly what it says: i must be final (or effectively final, meaning that compiler must be able to deduce that the variable will never change.

In your case, `i` changes (between 0 and 10), so it's not "effectively final".

What you want to do is add a variable to hold the current snapshot of `i` and store it in a final variable; for example on the top of the loop add:

```
final int snapshot = i;
```

If you think about it, this Java behavior is very logical - by the time any of the listeners fire, the loop in question is over, so there is no such thing as *current value of i*. Instead, there's a *snapshot of i value taken during the iteration when the listener was established*.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Where should I add the final in the program? I tried few different positions but gives me errors